# How to show multiple record if has top 1

Tags: sql-server, join, query, subquery, top

Hi currently having difficulty to query the result sorry a newbie here. i am trying to find the result of these two tables. i want to get all the records on table 2 with an effective date < 2019-12-05.

Table 1

Key 2          Name

---

```
78     Test 1 
222    Test 2            
824    Test 3  
1980   Test 4
3747   Test 5
```

Please see image for table 2[image]

```
select top 1 (md2.table2) from table2 md2
where md2.EFFECTIVEDATE < '2019-12-05'
and md2.key2 in (select key2 from table1)
order by EFFECTIVEDATE desc
```

my query only getting one record i want to get all the record on key 2

Comment: I guess that removing the TOP (1) doesn't give you what you want?  If you mock up a result set of what you are looking for, we can probably guide you better, right now it's hard to tell what your objective is.

Comment: Are you willing to get the top 1 for each Key2?

Comment: "I want to get all records", but your query is `SELECT TOP 1 ...`. Isn't it obvious that the `TOP 1` is causing it not to display all records?  Have you tried removing the `TOP 1`?

Answer (score 2):

Top is only giving you one record because you're asking for the top '1' row.  If you want all, just change it to:

```
select (md2.table2) from table2 md2
where md2.EFFECTIVEDATE < '2019-12-05'
and md2.key2 in (select key2 from table1)
order by EFFECTIVEDATE desc
```